# "WARNING no tools available, attempting to retrieve from amazonaws" while bootstraping

Tags: juju, maas

I have installed MAAS server with DHCP and DNS. Next I added two nodes, they turned green.

However, when I use Juju bootstrap there is an error:

```
WARNING no tools available, attempting to retrieve from https://juju-dist.s3.amazonaws.com/
```

the images are downloaded and Juju starts the nodes and installs Ubuntu on them, but after the installation is finished the screen turns black and there is no action.

In the Web interface the nodes are blue and there is 2 nodes allocated. The nodes are allocated to my profile name.

When I run `juju status` the command hangs and nothing happens.

Can you please give me some advices? Thanks you are the best!

---

Hello and thanks for the answer you are the best. But now i have this:

```
environment: maas
    machines:   
        "0":
            agent-state: started
            agent-version: 1.16.3.1
            dns-name: nkdbe.master
            instance-id: /MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-650ff85c-6884-11e3-a0ea-002590925e2e/
            series: precise
        "1":
            agent-state: started
            agent-version: 1.16.3.1
            dns-name: pat7e.master
            instance-id: /MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-7d7afc70-688e-11e3-98cd-002590925e2e/
            series: precise
    services:
        juju-gui:
            charm: cs:precise/juju-gui-81
            exposed: true
        units:
            juju-gui/0:
                agent-state: started
                agent-version: 1.16.3.1
                machine: "1"
                open-ports:
                    - 80/tcp
                    - 443/tcp
                public-address: pat7e.master
```

When i try to open pat7e.master in a web browser no address found. What should i do?

---

Hello i have installed juju and now i'm trying to install juju gui. When i write juju status :
 agent-state: started
    agent-version: 1.16.3.1
    dns-name: 7dbb8.master
    instance-id: /MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-66915cbe-67d7-11e3-bea0-002590925e2e/
    series: precise
  "1":
    agent-state-info: '(error: cannot run instances: gomaasapi: got error back from
      server: 409 CONFLICT)'
    instance-id: pending
    series: precise
services:
  juju-gui:
    charm: cs:precise/juju-gui-81
    exposed: true
    units:
      juju-gui/0:
        agent-state: pending
        machine: "1"

i've got this. Can you please give me advice what kind of error is this and how can i fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `agent-state-info` line describes the error that MAAS returned when trying to provision machine 1, and probably indicates that there aren't any "ready" nodes that can be allocated to the environment.

- To get a GUI running, you can deploy straight to the bootstrap node, and not require any additional hardware:

  ```
  $ juju add-unit juju-gui --to 0
  ```
- To clear up the useless machine that failed provisioning:

  ```
  $ juju destroy-unit juju-gui/0
  $ juju destroy-machine 1
  ```

  ...or, if you're running the latest version, you can just do:

  ```
  $ juju destroy-machine 1 --force
  ```

  ...which will clean up all its units automatically for you.
- To make your next deploy work well, check your MAAS GUI; it sounds as though you might not have any "ready" nodes for juju to allocate. The only node allocated should be the one that you bootstrapped onto -- if you allocated the other one manually, and now have none marked "ready", you need to either release that node or add new ones to the cluster, so that juju has at least one "ready" node to deploy onto.